# Keep some specific values in a DataFrame and set to zero the others

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dataframe, apply

I have created a function as follows

```
def element(x):
    return x*1 if x > 0.09 else x*0
```

and I have a dataframe as follows:

```
    index   FACTOR1     FACTOR2     FACTOR3
0   ECON1   0.0955037   0.0297977   0.0148448
1   ECON2   0.00505775  0.142272    0.0516773
2   ECON2   0.0360157   0.0115226   0.133393
3   FOOD1   0.106315    0.000673806 0.0264848
4   FOOD2   0.0188154   0.0344419   0.138877
5   FOOD3   0.00941108  0.1851     0.000474615
```

I d like to keep the values bigger than a threshold (say 0.09 - see function above) and set others to zeros.

I applied the following function but it did not work

```
display(df.apply(element, subset=Variable_Names) )
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: ("element() got an unexpected keyword argument 'subset'", 'occurred at index FACTOR1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, look at the documentation of the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method. If you are calling `df.apply(element, subset=Variable_Names)` like this, you provide an additional argument `subset` to the function `element` (and this is not expected by that function).

Secondly, you should choose only the numerical part of your dataframe to apply your function:

```
df.loc[:, Variable_Names]
```

Thirdly, if you apply this function to your DataFrame just like this you will get

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index FACTOR1')
```

because apply passes columns (by default) or rows (with option `axis=1`) to your function, which is not adapted for an array input (inequality of an array and a number returns an array of booleans, while `if` expects only one value).

So, what you can do is:

1. use [applymap()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df.loc[:, Variable_Names] = df.loc[:, Variable_Names].applymap(element)
```

2. use [np.vectorize()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
df.loc[:, Variable_Names] = df.loc[:, Variable_Names].apply(np.vectorize(element))
```

both giving the desierd output:

```
    index   FACTOR1     FACTOR2     FACTOR3
0   ECON1   0.095504    0.000000    0.000000
1   ECON2   0.000000    0.142272    0.000000
2   ECON2   0.000000    0.000000    0.133393
3   FOOD1   0.106315    0.000000    0.000000
4   FOOD2   0.000000    0.000000    0.138877
5   FOOD3   0.000000    0.185100    0.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to identify only `numeric` columns from `df`.

Then use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to check values which are greater than the threshold and assign the rest to `0` :

```
In [2897]: import numpy as np

In [2915]: threshold = 0.09

In [2898]: cols = df.select_dtypes('number').columns

In [2911]: df[cols] = np.where(df[cols].gt(threshold), df[cols], 0)

In [2912]: df
Out[2912]: 
   index   FACTOR1   FACTOR2   FACTOR3
0  ECON1  0.095504  0.000000  0.000000
1  ECON2  0.000000  0.142272  0.000000
2  ECON2  0.000000  0.000000  0.133393
3  FOOD1  0.106315  0.000000  0.000000
4  FOOD2  0.000000  0.000000  0.138877
5  FOOD3  0.000000  0.185100  0.000000
```